# Can not switch to inner html code in iframe by selenium-java

Tags: selenium, innerhtml

[html code screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q0Dze.png)

This is my code (Chrome driver, java). I have already used all types of waits and even `Thread.sleep()`:

```
    frame = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//iframe[@class='x-component x-window-item x-component-default']"));
    driver.switchTo().frame(frame);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[text()='Exporting basic player data ...']")); // There no such element exception
```

Comment: what error you are getting?

Comment: Which _Selenium Language Binding Art_ are you using? _Java_ / _Python_ / _C#_ / _NodeJS_ ? Update the question with the text based HTML

Comment: Please paste the code as text into your question then highlight and press Ctrl+K this allows us to copy and paste your code into our IDEs and help identify the problem. Please read [how to create a Minimal, Complete, Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to know what code you need to include

Comment: what if you try `frame = driver.findElement(By.name('outputContainer'))` and then `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(text(),'Exporting basic player data')]"))`

Comment: NoSuchElementExeption when I try to find span(is inside iframe) after switching to iframe

Answer (score -1):

You don't have an ellipsis (`...`) in your actual code, right? Or is that the exact text in the span element?

Try this instead:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(text(), 'Exporting')]"));
```